# I Am Getting An Error When Importing Sklearn

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn

i am getting an error when trying to import `import sklearn.metrics.pairwise as pw` how do i fix this?

full error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found.

import: import sklearn.metrics.pairwise as pw

```
traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
  self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
  all_issues = checks.run_checks(
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
  new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
  return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
  return check_method()
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
  for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
  res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
  patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
  res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
  return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Humza\Recommend_Me_Entertainment\Recommend_Me_Entertainment\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
  from home import views
File "C:\Users\Humza\Recommend_Me_Entertainment\home\views.py", line 16, in <module>
  import sklearn.metrics.pairwise as pw
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
  from .base import clone
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 21, in <module>
  from .utils import _IS_32BIT
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py", line 7, in <module>
  from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 26, in <module>
  from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
  import scipy.stats
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 388, in <module>
  from .stats import *
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 180, in <module>
  from . import distributions
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 8, in <module>
  from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 23, in <module>
  from scipy import optimize
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 387, in <module>
  from .optimize import *
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 36, in <module>
  from ._numdiff import approx_derivative
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_numdiff.py", line 6, in <module>
  from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
  from .eigen import *
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  from .arpack import *
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  from .arpack import *
File "C:\Users\Humza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 43, in <module>
  from . import _arpack
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

try remove and re-install the sklearn package

```
conda remove --force numpy, scipy, scikit-learn
```

or

```
conda remove scikit-learn
```

and install using `pip`

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```